# tinyMCE list control with single style option / no dropdown

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

You can control the available styles for the bullet-list and number-list as outlined in the [documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/advlist/#advlist_number_styles):

```
tinymce.init({
  ...
  plugins: "advlist",
  advlist_bullet_styles: "square",  // only include square bullets in list
  advlist_number_styles: "lower-alpha",  // only include lower alpha in list
  ...
});
```

However, when there is only one style the dropdown is still present, with the single style option. There is no need for the dropdown with one item. How can you get rid of the dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to only use the default list types (circle and number), this can be achieved by not using the advanced list plugin. Check your plugins for

```
tinymce.init({
  ...
  plugins: [ ... 'advlist', ...],
  ...
});
```

and simply remove 'advlist'. There will be no dropdown and the list styles will be default. If you want to use a single non-default style option provided by the 'advlist' plugin, the answer isn't clear.